# attempting to rewrite index.aspx to SEO friendly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to rewrite

```
/products/index.aspx?m=CISCO&c=REF&p=DS-C24-300AC
```

into

```
CISCO-DS-C24-300AC.html
```

I am currently configured my rule this far but I can't see why this doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^products/index.aspx?m=(.*)&c=([^/.]+)&p=([^/.]+)$ $1-$3.html [R=301,L]
```

I have also used

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /products/index.aspx?m=$1&c=REF&p=$2
```

Any help that anyone could offer, I would be very grateful.  I just can't seem to figure out where I am missing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completed this via the following

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=(.*)&c=([^/.]+)&p=([^/.]+)
 RewriteRule ^products/index.aspx?$ /%1-%3.html? [R=301,L]
```